# system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()

Tags: apex, email

I'm trying to send the link of a record in the mail and I do not want to hard code the base url. So I'm using `system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()` and the appending the record's ID.

```
string body = 'The Record already exists. It is not cloned. Click on the link' + system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl() +'/'+opp1.Id + ' to go to the record!';
```

But in my mail, I'm getting the link as
linkUrl:`[delegate=https://ap2.salesforce.com]/00628000006ohcPAAQ`

Tried to search where I was going wrong but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string body = 'The Record already exists. It is not cloned. Click on the link' 
                + system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() 
                +'/'+opp1.Id + ' to go to the record!';
```

Use `system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()` method. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Even better: `new Url(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl(), '/'+opp1.id)`. This makes sure the url is as you expect.

Comment: @sfdcfox  I think this should be `new Url(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl(), '/opp1.id').toExternalForm()` ? let me know if I am correct?

Comment: The string is wrong, but you're I  the right area. There's a constructor that accepts one Url plus one string.